# Alert a message only if using Internet Explorer 10+

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, alert

I manage a website with 100+ pages and recently updated to use Bootstrap-4 and Flexbox. Problem is that many of the pages break when viewed via Internet Explorer 10+. Rather than rewrite the code to target Internet Explorer, we would like to popup a message within a modal recommending the user upgrade their browser. But I only want this message to appear if the user is using IE to view our website. Since conditional comments are disabled in IE10 they are not an option. I've searched SO and google looking for an answer but not having any luck.

Comment: Take a look at these links: https://blog.blakesimpson.co.uk/page.php?id=79&title=detect-internet-explorer-10-without-conditional-comments and https://codepen.io/gapcode/pen/vEJNZN You can change the code to bring up your modal or alert.

Comment: Thanks rgiller for your quick response. I'll try that and see if it does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a test with code below may help you to identify IE 10 version.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Page Title</title>
 <script>
 if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 10") !== -1)
{
    window.alert('This is IE 10');
}
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 sample text
</body>
</html>
```

Output in IE 10:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found `@supports (display: grid) {` to be effective with this issue and it has a fallback for older browsers that do not support flexbox.